# Multiple selection of enum

Tags: newmips

I have an enum (Writing, Phone, Face-to-face) but sometimes I have to select more than one (when an email is followed by a phone call). The standard web widget is a set of checkboxes.

How do I do it (i.e., make a group of checkboxes)?

Is there a magic button or word to tell Mipsy that this enum has to be converted into a group of checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple select and group of checkboxes are new field types. This feature is planned in the release 2.4 (October 2017).